# snapsvg (Cannot read property 'attr' of null)

Tags: javascript, svg, snapsvg

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка? Картинка в блок грузится, но атрибут отказывается работать.

HTML

```
<div id="board"></div>
```

JS

```
var board, choice, choiceGroup;

board = Snap("#board");

Snap.load("img/board.svg", function (data) {
    board.append(data);

    choice = board.select("#choice");
    choiceGroup = board.select("#choice-g");

    choice.attr({transform: "t100,0"});
});
```

В консоли выдает такую ошибку.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null
    at main.js:13
    at snap.svg.js:2648
    at f2 (snap.svg.js:452)
    at eve (snap.svg.js:137)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (snap.svg.js:2626)
```

Comment: судя из этого кода html должен выглядеть так: <div {transform: t100,0}> но такого атрибута не существует, и по идее html должен проигнорировать этот атрибут. Может стоит сделать что-то типа: choice.attr('какой-то реально существующий в svg атрибут', 'transform: t100, 0') ?

Comment: transform - просто для примера ввел. оно и пустым не работает.
вообще transform на выходе в html выведет transform="matrix(0,0,1,1,0,0)" - цифры как пример.

Comment: тогда в роли атрибута пусть будет attr('style', 'transform: t100,0')

Comment: наверно нужно было упомянуть что это библиотека snapsvg
там трансформ не идет в style, это отдельный атрибут.

Comment: окей, тогда какой атрибут за это отвечает? что-то работающее уже ж есть?

Comment: У вас не атрибут не существует, а `choice === null`. Читайте внимательнее ошибки

Comment: Есть рабочий пример, все по такому же принципу,.
https://jsfiddle.net/rbp72zbs/
Но здесь attr работает.

Comment: сорри, реально не умею читать внимательно.
в самом svg файле  не было id = choice